# Node/Express.js - array elements are disappearing

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express, web-development-server

I am trying to put some information out of a database into an array, so that I can continue working with it. However, after the elements got added within a for-loop, they disappear and it returns an empty array.

```
// PROBLEM: all_prices-elements disappear TODO
// creates a price list

var all_prices = []; // all the prices
for (var i=0; i<query_id_list.length; i++) {
    if (Object.keys(query_id_list[i]).length != 0) {
        Toy.find(query_id_list[i], (err, toys) => {
            if (!err) {
                for (var i=0; i<toys.length; i++) {
                    var toyPrice = toys[i].price;
                    all_prices.push(toyPrice);
                }
            } else {
                res.json({});
            }
      });
    } else {
    res.json({});
    }
}

console.log(all_prices); // returns []
```

Here is the Toy Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// note: your host/port number may be different!
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myDatabase');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var toySchema = new Schema( {
    id: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    price: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Toy', toySchema);
```

Comment: can you post toy and related schema.i may help you to get escape from weird looping hell

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `console.log` inside the callback of `mongoose` query

**THIS CODE**

```
var all_prices = []; // all the prices

for (var i=0; i<query_id_list.length; i++) {
if (Object.keys(query_id_list[i]).length != 0) {
    Toy.find(query_id_list[i], (err, toys) => {
        if (!err) {
            for (var i=0; i<toys.length; i++) {
                var toyPrice = toys[i].price;
                all_prices.push(toyPrice);
            }
        } else {
            res.json({});
        }
  });
} else {
  res.json({});
 }
}
console.log(all_prices); // returns []
```

**Should be**

```
// creates a price list

var all_prices = []; // all the prices
for (var i=0; i<query_id_list.length; i++) {
    if (Object.keys(query_id_list[i]).length != 0) {
        Toy.find(query_id_list[i], (err, toys) => {
            if (!err) {
                for (var i=0; i<toys.length; i++) {
                    var toyPrice = toys[i].price;
                    all_prices.push(toyPrice);
                }
              console.log(all_prices); // returns all_prices
            } else {
                res.json({});
            }
      });
    } else {
    res.json({});
    }
}
```

Comment: lt prints out the prices on the console, I already figured that out, but I actually need the array with the elements in it, so that I can continue working with it. The console.log is just for debugging